# PHP dates not iterating correctly

Tags: php, date, datetime

I was trying to iterate dates from the `first day of this month` to the `last day of April`:

```
$month_start = new DateTime("first day of this month");
$month_end = new DateTime("last day of April");

while ($month_start <= $month_end) {
    echo $month_start->format("Y-m-d\n");
    $month_start->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

Output ([demo](https://3v4l.org/enAUu)) as of March 22<sup>nd</sup> 2020:

```
2020-03-01
2020-03-02
2020-03-03
...
2020-04-27
2020-04-28
2020-04-29
```

As you can see, April 30th is missing from the output, despite the use of `<=` in the comparison. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to an inconsistency in the way the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) constructor handles `first day of` relative times:

```
$month_start = new DateTime("first day of this month");
echo $month_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
$month_start = new DateTime("first day of March");
echo $month_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Output ([demo](https://3v4l.org/lG3GL)) as of March 22<sup>nd</sup> 2020:

```
2020-03-01 03:49:52
2020-03-01 00:00:00
```

Notice that the `first day of this month` variable has non-zero time parts. When you compute the `$month_end` value though, you get a zero time:

```
$month_end = new DateTime("last day of April");
echo $month_end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Output ([demo](https://3v4l.org/L9GoE)):

```
2020-04-30 00:00:00
```

So the loop in the code fails because because `$month_start` gets to `2020-04-30` with a non-zero time, where `$month_end` has a zero time and thus the `<=` comparison fails.

You can work around this by adding a time portion to the first value to force it to 0:

```
$month_start = new DateTime("first day of this month 00:00");
```

And your loop will then work as expected: [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/esUUj).